# Propagating Schrodinger equation

Tags: algorithms, quantum-mechanics

My task is to simulate quantum evolution. To do that I need to perform this operation

$$w = e^{-itH}v$$

where $H$ is a sparse matrix and $v$ is the initial column vector. I am wondering if there is a way to calculate vector $w$ without evaluating the MatrixExp? What I mean is: if $t$ is really small (time step) is there some kind of an algorithm (stable and accurate) which uses only matrix-vector multiplication?

For example:

$$w(t) = \left(e^{-i\frac{t}{n}H}\right)^{n}v\\
\frac{t}{n} = dt$$
Algorithm would go like this:
$$w(0) = v \\
w(dt) = e^{-idtH}w(0)\\
w(2dt) = e^{-idtH}w(dt)\\
\ldots$$

and I don't know, replace 
$$e^{-idtH}\approx 1 -idtH$$

One thing should remain unchanged: norm of the vector $||w(t)||=1$

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Godric Seer's suggestion, you can also use rational approximations to the exponential, e.g.

$e^z = \frac{1 + z/2}{1 - z/2} + \mathcal{O}(z^3)$,

to devise more accurate approximations to the matrix exponential:

$e^{-itH} \approx (I + itH)^{-1}(I - itH)$.

This approximation has the advantage of being a unitary operator, so that in exact arithmetic $\|w\|$ remains unchanged. Of course you have to watch out in floating point arithmetic if the condition number of $H$ is very large.

The paper [19 Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf) is worth a read, and if you want to dig deeper, [Saad's book](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1611970733) is both very readable and very comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

By definition

$e^{idtH} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left( i dt H\right)^k$

which is easily approximated by truncating the sum after a number of terms.  Ideally you would want to use only two terms so that

$e^{i dt H} \approx 1 + i dt H$

What that means is that $\frac{1}{2}(i dt H)^2$ must have a small effect on the solution.  Assuming $H$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, then you need $dt^2 \lambda_i^2 << 1$ for every eigenvalue.  As long as you choose a small enough $dt$ that this is true, you can avoid the matrix exponential with only the first two terms of the sum.

Comment: This is actually very bad idea [link](http://www.fh.huji.ac.il/~ronnie/Papers/k71.pdf) Better way is to use SOD algorithm or Expansion of Exponential function in Chebyshev polynomials

Comment: I agree that this is likely the roughest and least efficient way to approximate the exponent, but since the question started heading this way, I wanted to give a criteria for it.

Answer (score 1):

Is H time-dependent? If not, can not you just diagonalize H, and then express your initial vector "v" as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of H, and then propagate those?

If H is time-dependent, another technique (in addition to those already mentioned) would be to use a split operator technique like the Trotter decomposition.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be the best way if my hamiltonian is the same during calculations - just diagonalize it once and store diagonal vector with transition matrix in a memory. However, imagine at every momemt of time You have a collection of different hamiltonians (simulating noise) to calculate mean vector - I am not sure if diagonalization is better than MatrixExp algorithm?